# Django model saving on User login

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class Project (models.Model):
    ''' Defines a project '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
    name = models.CharField (
        verbose_name = _('Project Title'),
        max_length = 100
    )

    dt_created = models.DateTimeField(editable = False)
    dt_lastmod = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = ProjectManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
          self.dt_created = timezone.now()
        self.dt_lastmod = timezone.now()

        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view-project', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

When the 'User' linked to the model through the `user` field logs in, the model saves and the dt_lastmod is reset.

Why?  How do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Looks like there is some logic that loads related `Projects`s, etc. I think it also might be worth to work with `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`, since this is a more declarative way to handle this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now

Comment: Do you by any change, when the user is logged in, have a page that for example renders the project, and calls `.save()` on these `Project`s.

Comment: I've tried that and I get the same result

Comment: well then clearly something in the login process, or the page where the login redirects to, saves the projects, but here it is hard to help with that. What might help is set a breakpoint on the `.save()` method, and see when it is called.

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. Put `raise` inside `save` (or breakpoint), see callstack.

Comment: Bloody obvious - problem is a signal - thanks.  Breakpoint found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this just to close it.

The issue was I had a signal set elsewhere which was picking up on the user being loaded and saved (because last_login was changing) and was doing some processing on this whereas the processing was only needed if a specific field changed.